# How do I testfor a player that crouch wearing a chestplate that is named?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I try to make a sort of ability that implies wearing a special chestplate! When a player wear it and crouch, the ability shoud be activated! I just want to know how can I testfor crouching (the "stat.sneakTime" or "CrouchOneCm" scoreboard doesn't help me)

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/226838/how-can-i-detect-if-a-player-is-wearing-a-specific-piece-of-armour/226861#226861

Comment: Why doesn't `stat.sneakTime` work for you? Is it just that you are unsure how to use it? Or the combination with the armor?

Comment: I didn't want to detect if a player wears an armor, I want to detect if a player is crouching wearing an armor

Comment: I know, that's why it's related and not a duplicate.

Comment: I am not sure how to use the sneakTime or CrouchOneCm !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To tag only those wearing the special chestplate, have these two commands repeating in this order:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=SpecialChestplate] remove SpecialChestplate
/scoreboard players tag @a add SpecialChestplate {Inventory:[{Slot:102b,tag:{display:{Name:"Special Chestplate"}}}]}
```

You should replace `tag:{display:{Name:"Special Chestplate"}}` with the data you want to identify your chestplate by (e.g: lore, enchantments), I've just used the name "Special Chestplate" for this example.

---

To check for who's sneaking, first create a `stat.sneakTime` objective:

```
/scoreboard objectives add SneakTime stat.sneakTime
```

Then, add onto your repeating command blocks in this order:

```
/say @a[tag=SpecialChestplate,score_SneakTime_min=1]
/scoreboard players set @a[score_SneakTime_min=1] SneakTime 0
```

The second command will set `SneakTime` to 0 at the end of the tick, meaning that only players who are currently sneaking will have a `SneakTime` of 1 for the next tick. If a player stops sneaking, their `SneakTime` will go to 0.

The `/say` command is where you should put the blocks for your ability, using the `@a[tag=SpecialChestplate,score_SneakTime_min=1]` selector.